# Making it look like the computer is thinking in TicTacToe game

Tags: vb.net

here is a slice of code that i've written in VB.net

```
Private Sub L00_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles L00.Click, L01.Click, L02.Click, L03.Click, L10.Click, L11.Click, L12.Click, L13.Click, L20.Click, L21.Click, L22.Click, L23.Click, L30.Click, L31.Click, L32.Click, L33.Click
    Dim ticTac As Label = CType(sender, Label)
    Dim strRow As String
    Dim strCol As String

    'Once a move is made, do not allow user to change whether player/computer goes first, because it doesn't make sense to do so since the game has already started.
    ComputerFirstStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
    PlayerFirstToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False

    'Check to make sure clicked tile is a valid tile i.e and empty tile.
    If (ticTac.Text = String.Empty) Then
        ticTac.Text = "X"
        ticTac.ForeColor = ColorDialog1.Color
        ticTac.Tag = 1


        'After the player has made his move it becomes the computers turn.
        computerTurn(sender, e)

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please pick an empty tile to make next move", "Invalid Move")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub computerTurn(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Call Randomize()
    row = Int(4 * Rnd())
    col = Int(4 * Rnd())

    'Check to make sure clicked tile is a valid tile i.e and empty tile.
    If Not ticTacArray(row, col).Tag = 1 And Not ticTacArray(row, col).Tag = 4 Then
        ticTacArray(row, col).Text = "O"
        ticTacArray(row, col).ForeColor = ColorDialog2.Color
        ticTacArray(row, col).Tag = 4

        checkIfGameOver(sender, e)
    Else
        'Some good ole pseudo-recursion(doesn't require a base case(s)).
        computerTurn(sender, e)
    End If

End Sub
```

Everything works smoothly, except i'm trying to make it seem like the computer has to "think" before making its move. So what i've tried to do is place a System.Threading.Sleep() call in different places in the code above.

The problem is that instead of making the computer look like its thinking, the program waits and then puts the X and O together at the same time. Can someone help me make it so that the program puts an X wherever i click AND THEN wait before it places an O?

Edit: in case any of you are wondering, i realize that the computers AI is ridiculously dumb, but its just to mess around right now. Later on i will implement a serious AI..hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Greg said I would use a Timer, I would first take the logic out of your computerTurn Click event and create a Method, you could use a random number generator to make it seem like the amout of time that the computer was think varied, then you could for instance, change the Cursor to the Wait Cursor. Something like this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim rnd As Random = New Random(1)
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        Timer1.Interval = CInt(rnd.NextDouble * 1000)
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Timer1.Stop()
        computerTurn()
    End Sub

    Private Sub computerTurn()
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
       'Your Move Logic Here
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, when does Timer1_tick get called? It looks like its called after the passage of every time interval, but i only want to call computerTurn() after the player makes his move..

Comment: @rage It would be generated by what every method you are using to start the Computers turn. The reason I used a button was because your ComputerTurn Method had an Event signature

Comment: Actually would i need to add a Timer1.Stop() in order to achieve the functionality i'm looking for ?

Comment: Yea, i took that out of the method arguments. I think i understand your example though and i'm about to test it out.

Comment: Lol it works! but it then continues to place "O" all over the board. Thats why i asked if i would need a timer1.stop()-esque method

Comment: @rage I am sorry I forgot that. I edited my code to include it

Comment: It's cool. I'm glad you were able to point me in the right direction!

Comment: I also learned in class another way to do this: Me.Refresh() before a System.Threading.Sleep() call.

Comment: @rage that will work allowing the screen to refresh, but I still would not use a blocking call in your main ui thread

Answer (score 1):

In general, the solution for this sort of problem is to set up a *timer* to display the calculated computer move later. The problem is that (in general) VB.NET does not allow the screen to update while your code is running. So when you add a sleep, even if you have already told the display to show the player X, the screen won't actually reflect that until your function returns, after the sleep.

You'll have to look up how to use a timer object in VB.NET (I don't know the details off the top of my head). Because there will be time between the player move and the computer move, you'll also want to make sure that the player can't move *twice* before the computer gets a chance (so make a variable that changes depending on whose turn it is).

Answer (score 0):

Separation of concerns.

Build a method that tells you what move the computer wants to make. Have that method do it's job as well and efficiently as possible, and return the entire result back to your presentation code. It's up to the presentation level to then decide what to do with that move, which may include waiting or animating something to make it appear that the computer is thinking.